Issur Matzav & Issur Ma’aseh
Around 45 minutes into a shiur on Shehiyah, Rabbi Eliezer Krohn said in the name of the Chazon Ish that if you put on a food item in a forbidden manner, not accounting for the kulas of Chazal to permit it, before the item reaches ma’achal ben Drusai, before Shabbat, and it cooks into Shabbat, it is assur to eat it b’di’eved and you can’t simply do teshuvah later on.
The phrase he used was that it is an “איסור מצב” rather than an “איסור מעשה,” in the sense that the איסור applies to the condition itself rather than only to the action.
Are there any klalim in terms of differentiating between these two types of issurim?
L’choira, for example, for a healthy adult Yisroel to be uncircumcised would be an איסור מצב, but are there general principles governing which issurim fall into either category?

Can you include a link to the shiur?

done, yasher koach!
